# Visual Studio Code custom color gets overwritten?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, color-scheme

These are my custom color settings in **settings.json**:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
   "textMateRules": [{
      "name": "Object keys, TS grammar specific",
      "scope": [
         "meta.object-literal.key",
         "support.object.key",
         "support.type",
         "support.type.property-name.json",
         "entity.name.type",
         "entity.other.attribute",
         "entity.name.namespace",
         "entity.name.scope-resolution",
         "entity.name.class",
         "storage.type.object.array.java",
         "storage.type.primitive.array.java",
         "storage.type.parameters.groovy",
         "storage.type.object.array.groovy",
      ],
      "settings": {
         "foreground": "#ff3300"
      }
   }]
}
```

As I only code in Javascript, there is some apparently useless stuff in the scope, but I was trying to bash any possible parameter, desperately trying to override the theme behaviour responsible for the overwriting. Of course, not knowing what I'm doing, I failed.

I thought I had made some sort of mistake, but if I restart VSC it DOES work, just for 1 or 2 seconds, then it automatically resets to the theme standard (the base team is VSC Dark standard).

:
[On start:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmRgt.png)

[After a couple seconds:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBrdR.png)

I have no "beautifying" or graphical extensions.
VSC is updated to last version.
What causes the overwrite, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I just noticed something: in the settings.json the effects are applied and not overwritten by the misterious culprit, so my custom settings do work there. Not only that, I noticed the blue object-keys shouldn't be the standard behaviour since, as you can see here (https://i.imgur.com/oXzG8ze.png) there's another expected color for object keys, different from my custom (another red shade).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to settings.
- Turn off semantic highlighting